# How to reset Ubuntu's theme?

Tags: unity

I was wondering how to reset Ubuntu's theme to default because I installed a new theme and now everything is broken despite already resetting the theme.

When I logout it goes to a blank screen and says low graphics mode and I can't do anything else so I have to reboot.

[image: THEME]

I am unable to show you the login screen and in gnome session nothing loads it is blank.

Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: What theme did you try to install? and how?

Comment: @wilf I used this: http://www.noobslab.com/2014/01/flattastic-themes-pack-for-ubuntulinux.html

I used Gnome tweak to enable the theme

Comment: Not Unity Tweak? Try `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Ambiance'` or `sudo apt-get purge flattastic-suite`. You can also try reporting the problem to [the devloper](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/themes). The packages you installed may of replaced the existing default ones, which might of caused the problem and might be why resetting the theme did not work.

Comment: You might also want to remove the ppa: `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge` then `sudo ppa-purge ppa:noobslab/themes`. You can do these commands from tty - press Ctrl + Alt + F2 for for `tty2`, and Ctrl + Alt + F7 to return to the graphical tty.